# Is there any Rossetta 2 (SBT Static Binary Translation) alternative on Linux?

Tags: linux, kvm, qemu, arm, x86

On an Apple Silicon chip such as M1 (ARMv8), x86 instructions can be translated statistically by Rossetta 2 when the program runs for the first time. It's fast. Because Rossetta 2 does the SBT (Static Binary Translation).

I had used `qemu` to emulated an x86_64 Linux OS on a M1 MacBook Pro and it worked. But `qemu` is doing the JIT (Just-in-time compilation),the performance is so bad, very slow, hardly usable.

Is there any public implementation (opensource?) for doing the SBT on ARM64 based Linux which can run x86 instructions faster?

Comment: 1. no.  probably because no-one really cares enough about binary-only software on linux when you can just recompile the source.  2. why try to run amd64 on an ARMv8 Mac? Why not just run an arm v8 linux on it? there are several distros with arm versions available.

Comment: @cas reason why: I need to run all those x86 programs and deploy them more more conveniently on an ARM64 processor, later on I will have enough time to rebuild all of the x86 apps into ARM64 apps. Also I need to develop x86 apps for x86 servers if I only have an ARM64 (M1) processor.